# Mock test always stops at isEmpty checking and throw an exception

Tags: java, rest, testing, mocking

I've written test for update method in service layer and it always throws an exception "User with the this id is not found" and didn't work.
I've tried to add optional but it didn't work too.
Could you give me a little piece of advice please? What should I fix in my test?
**My testing method looks like:**

```
@Override
public UserDTO updateUser(String id, UserDTO updatedUser) {
    Optional<UserEntity> databaseUser = userRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(updatedUser.getUserName()));
    if (databaseUser.isEmpty()) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User with the this id is not found");
    }
    UserEntity entity = mapToUserEntity(updatedUser);
    return map(userRepository.save(entity));
}
```

**My test looks like:**

```
@Test
void updateUserTest(){
    final int id = 1;
    final long roleId = 2L;

    UserDTO userDto = new UserDTO();

    userDto.setUserName(String.valueOf(12));
    userDto.setId(String.valueOf(id));
    userDto.setName(new UserDTO.Name("surname", "firstname", "patronymic"));
    userDto.setActive(true);
    userDto.setEmails(List.of(new UserDTO.Email("email", "external")));
    userDto.setRoles(List.of("2"));
    userDto.setLastAccessDate(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 10, 25, 4, 20));
    userDto.setUnit(null);

    when(roleRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(new UserDTO().setId(roleId)));
    UserEntity userEntity = userService.mapToUserEntity(userDto);

    when(userRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(userEntity.setId(id));

    userService.updateUser(String.valueOf(id), userDto);

    var actualUser = userService.updateUser(String.valueOf(id), userDto);

    userDto.setUserName(String.valueOf(id));
    assertEquals(actualUser, userDto);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the call to `userRepository.findById` isn't mocked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I mock userRepository with @Mock annotation.

Comment: when(roleRepository.findById(any()))
why is it called roleRepository if you return an instance of user?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I mistakenly put "new UserDTO" in instead of new RoleEntity but it hasn't solved the problem after the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updateUser` method calls `userRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(updatedUser.getUserName()))`.

The test does not stub this method, so the `userRepository` mock object will use the default answer behaviour to return a value. The example code does not show how the `userRepository` mock is created, but if the default answer is not customised, it will use [`RETURNS_DEFAULTS`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEFAULTS) and return an empty `Optional` by default for methods returning `Optional`.

To make it return `userDto` instead, you should stub the method before calling `userService.updateUser` in the test:

```
when(userRepository.findById(12)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userEntity));
when(userRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(userEntity.setId(id));

userService.updateUser(String.valueOf(id), userDto);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've tried previously to stub this method, but it cannot be resolved like "when(userRepository.findById(12)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userDto));" because of Optional.of(userDto)

Comment: Sorry, @Jack, my mistake. That should have read `Optional.of(userEntity)`. I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Although, now that I read more carefully, it seems that you would want to be updating the fields of `databaseUser` from `updatedUser` rather than creating the new `UserEntity entity` instance.

Comment: Thanks! So, should I add to my test databaseUser to make it works?

Comment: If you want it to skip over the `if` block in `updateUser`, then `userRepository.findById` needs to return a non-empty `Optional`. It's as simple as that!